# tflite roadmap for LSTM

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I read in https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/roadmap : 
(last update from:  March 6th, 2019)
This item is still work in progress I assume:
"Add full support of conversion for LSTMs and RNNs"

What is the 2019 ETA for LSTM/RNN support, or LSTM/CNN support  (basically any LSTM model for that matter..) ?  even as experimental..

I am working on a highly critical (for the company/business) proof-of-concept model, which must utilize LSTM as it is, already established in the tensorflow.  I am now required to convert it to tflite, in which then an Android App will infer tflite in runtime for specific Mobility purpose / use-case.

Thank you.