# Tacotron With TensorFlow Lite

Tags: tensorflow, text-to-speech

Is it possible to use tacotron implementation with TensorFlow Lite?
I used keith ito's implementation of tacotron and I woud like to use TFLite.
But I don't know how to change the code. TFLite is about only the Inference?
Apparentley, I can't use Session, Variable and other things, righ?

Comment: This is not easy since some of the layers are not yet supported by tflite. See and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55812402/tflite-roadmap-for-lstm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55812402/tflite-roadmap-for-lstm. Also, it is too slow for mobile anyway, not much sense to put such a big network on the phone.